# Deploy multiple azure App Service Plans causes error "Web space with specified name already exists"

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

How can you deploy multiple App Service Plans in the same azure resource group project?

When I try to deploy two web application with the following resource section in the template:

```
"resources": [
  {
    "name": "[parameters('Plan1Name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
    "dependsOn": [ ],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "Plan1"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "[parameters('Plan1Name')]",
      "sku": "[parameters('Plan1SKU')]",
      "workerSize": "[parameters('Plan1WorkerSize')]",
      "numberOfWorkers": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "[parameters('Plan2Name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
    "dependsOn": [
    ],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "Plan2"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "[parameters('Plan2Name')]",
      "sku": "[parameters('Plan2SKU')]",
      "workerSize": "[parameters('Plan2WorkerSize')]",
      "numberOfWorkers": 1
    }
  }
],
```

I get the following error when I deploy:

```
[VERBOSE] 09:26:11 - Create template deployment 'azuredeploy-0318-0926'.
[ERROR] New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 09:26:16 - Resource 
[ERROR] Microsoft.Web/serverfarms 'Plan1' failed with message 'Web space with 
[ERROR] specified name already exists.'
[ERROR] At C:\dev\src\vs2015\projects\webappplandeploy\webappplandeploy\Scripts\Deploy-
[ERROR] AzureResourceGroup.ps1:98 char:1
[ERROR] + New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFil ...
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeplo 
[ERROR]    yment], Exception
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResou 
[ERROR]    rceGroupDeploymentCommand
[ERROR]  
[VERBOSE] 09:26:18 - Resource Microsoft.Web/serverfarms 'Plan2' provisioning status is succeeded
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to add this line to plan 2:

```
"dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('Plan1Name'))]"
],
```

During my research to fix this, I worked out that App Service Plans can't seem to handle multiple App Service Plans being created at the same time.  To get it working, I needed to add a dependency on all other App Service Plans so they chain, one after another.

```
  {
    "name": "[parameters('Plan2Name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
    "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('Plan1Name'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "Plan2"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "[parameters('Plan2Name')]",
      "sku": "[parameters('Plan2SKU')]",
      "workerSize": "[parameters('Plan2WorkerSize')]",
      "numberOfWorkers": 1
    }
  }
```

and I got this output:

```
[VERBOSE] 09:32:07 - Create template deployment 'azuredeploy-0318-0932'.
[VERBOSE] 09:32:11 - Resource Microsoft.Web/serverfarms 'Plan1' provisioning status is succeeded
[VERBOSE] 09:32:14 - Resource Microsoft.Web/serverfarms 'Plan2' provisioning status is succeeded
```

Comment: I have just experienced the same, the chaining seemed to help, but the problem popped up after a while. I was deploying both dynamic serverfarms, and ordinary serverfarms, with two different sets of apiVersions. I could got the error many times in a row, but after alligning the apiVersions, it went away. Now I am just crossing my fingers.